# Should I delete unused branches?

Tags: git, branch

I'm thinking about unused branched.

When I create new module I create new branch and name it with pattern "[task_id]-[shortDescription]" - for example: "4389-surveys". When I finish work on this branch I merge it to master and the branch lies unused.

Should I delete this branches or keep it for eventuality?
Which practice is better and recommended?

Comment: I can't see the point of keeping unused development branches around. They just add mess to your repository. A number of existing branches won't slow down `git` noticeably but they take some space and make output of `git branch` hard to read. Anyway, if changes have been merged to a public branch they shouldn't be amended but a new commit should be added so it doesn't make sense to keep old changes.

Comment: after merging it to master/main you can delete it. One reason that can be considered to keep it is if you like to keep track of the branch's history (e.g. who did what)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Credit** @masonk https://stackoverflow.com/a/3392942/ :

> Delete after merge is the usual way. This is why git branch -d checks
> to make sure that the branch is fully merged before it will delete.
>
> There are a few reasons that I can think of to keep a branch around:
> you might want to hold onto it in case you have bugs coming back once
> it hits production, or you might want a historical record.
>
> In either case, you have the option of tagging the head of the branch
> before you delete it. A tag is like a branch in that it is a pointer
> to a commit, except for a few minor differences:
>
> 1. porcelain usually doesn't display tags in exploratory commands like
>    git show-branch or tab-auto complete in checkout
> 2. checking one out doesn't set HEAD (you will be in a detached HEAD)
> 3. you can leave a "tag" note on top of the note on the commit that it
>    points at.
>
> This way you preserve history, and if you ever do need to bug fix, I
> recommend just creating a new branch off of master for the fix.